# why do_upload is not runing well in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

New user of CI,
i'm trying to make simple upload using the good way i think ( that's happened )
it's not runing.

simple controller,
simple form view,
simple model, loaded upload library with config paramaters
the path of userfile ( upload folder: 777) is correct

seems process normaly, but not file in folder, and when i'm testing
do_upload(), i have FALSE...? as if do_upload(); was not called

**Controller**

```
class Ct_admin_add extends CI_Controller {  

        public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('view_admin_header');
        $msg['msg_file'] = '';  

        $this->load->model('form_admin_add_model');

        if($this->input->post('Upload'))
        {
            $this->form_admin_add_model->do_upload();                       
        }

        $this->load->view('form_admin_add', $msg);  

        $this->load->view('view_admin_footer'); 
    }   
}
```

**the View**

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('ct_admin_add');?>
<?php echo form_upload('userfile');?><br />
<?php echo form_submit('Upload', 'Charger');?><br />
<?php echo $msg_file; ?>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

**the model**

```
<?php
class Form_admin_add_model extends CI_Model{

    var $userfile_path;
        function __construct()
    {
        // Call the Model constructor
        parent::__construct();
        $this->userfile_path = APPPATH.'../userfile/';
    }

    function do_upload()
    {       
            $config = array(
            'upload_path' => $this->userfile_path,
            'allowed_types' => 'gif|jpg|png',
            'max_size'=> '100',
            'max_width'  => '1024',
            'max_height' => '768',
            'overwrite' => TRUE,
            'encrypt_name' => FALSE,
            'remove_spaces' => TRUE
            );

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if ( ! is_dir($config['upload_path']) ) die("THE UPLOAD DIRECTORY DOES NOT EXIST");
        $test = $this->upload->do_upload();
        var_dump($test);        
    }
}
```

Any tips?

Comment: `var_dump($this->upload->display_errors());` instead of `$test`

Comment: Hi Mamdouh,
"The upload path does not appear to be valid."
that is weird, 'cause when i'm testing the path it's ok?

Comment: thanks Rahil as well, that give me a clue. but not fixed yed.
i don't understand why the folder ( allready created with 777 ) has been reconized before, but not now? i try to figure out.

Comment: in u.nix folder names are case sensitive, guess doing it right

Comment: i've passed a while ( there is sometime obscurantism with code )
i changed the name of userfile as './userfile/' but same story. is_dir send me back a FALSE. So i change at last the name of the folder as './upload/'  (as i threw a coin in a wish fontain) and it  sent me a 'TRUE'.... ( --' okayyy pragmatism appear after impassable Logic)
still setting in 777, do_upload() is not running yet.
... i dig again ...

Comment: Ok, i managed:
in most of example you will find
`$this->library('upload', $config);`
i have deleted this line and put my 'uplaod' in library autoload
(folder application/config).
Insteed of this last line i initialize the $config.
`$this->upload->initialize($config);`
the userfile_path become './upload/'

thank for help.